# How to implement the SharePoint "ShadowBox" feature in a web part?

Tags: 2010

I see this feature a lot in various pages, when you need to enter another level of information.  It is basically a popup in the center that covers about 80% of the page and casts an opaque background over the rest of the screen.  When you click OK or whatever it goes away.

Is this built in or will I have to use something like the jQuery ShadowBox add on to get it going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is built-in and is in the Javascript Framework of SharePoint.  You can start from this good [blog post](http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Using-the-SharePoint-2010-Modal-Dialog.aspx)!

Enjoy the new Dialog Framework!